# How to add payment filter in Order collection factory magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, sales-order, payment, magento2.3.5, order-collection

I need to add the "po_number" as filter in order collection factory, i am trying to implement this in the sales order history page using getOrders function in the **History.php**

**Full Code :**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Sm\SalesOrderGridTable\Block\Order;

use \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactoryInterface;

/**
 * Sales order history block
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class History extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'Magento_Sales::order/history.phtml';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_orderCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_customerSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config
     */
    protected $_orderConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection
     */
    protected $orders;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactoryInterface
     */
    private $orderCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config $orderConfig
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config $orderConfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_orderConfig = $orderConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('My Orders'));
    }

    /**
     * Provide order collection factory
     *
     * @return CollectionFactoryInterface
     * @deprecated 100.1.1
     */
    private function getOrderCollectionFactory()
    {
        if ($this->orderCollectionFactory === null) {
            $this->orderCollectionFactory = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(CollectionFactoryInterface::class);
        }
        return $this->orderCollectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Get customer orders
     *
     * @return bool|\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection
     */
    public function getOrders()
    {
        if (!($customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId())) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!$this->orders) {
            $this->orders = $this->getOrderCollectionFactory()->create($customerId)->addFieldToSelect(
                '*'
            )->addFieldToFilter(
                'status',
                ['in' => $this->_orderConfig->getVisibleOnFrontStatuses()]
            )->addFieldToFilter(
                'entity_id',
                ['num' => 362]
            )->setOrder(
                'ext_order_id',
                'desc'
            );
        }
        $this->orders->getSelect()
        ->join(
            ["sop" => $this->getTable("sales_order_payment")],
            'main_table.entity_id = sop.parent_id'
        )
        ->where('sop.po_number = ?','08RRR');

        echo "<pre>"; print_r($this->orders->getData()); die("dead");
        return $this->orders;
    }
}
```

**Specific get Orders():**

```
public function getOrders()
        {
            if (!($customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId())) {
                return false;
            }
            if (!$this->orders) {
                $this->orders = $this->getOrderCollectionFactory()->create($customerId)->addFieldToSelect(
                    '*'
                )->addFieldToFilter(
                    'status',
                    ['in' => $this->_orderConfig->getVisibleOnFrontStatuses()]
                )->addFieldToFilter(
                    'entity_id',
                    ['num' => 362]
                )->setOrder(
                    'ext_order_id',
                    'desc'
                );
            }
            $this->orders->getSelect()
            ->join(
                ["sop" => $this->getTable("sales_order_payment")],
                'main_table.entity_id = sop.parent_id'
            )
            ->where('sop.po_number = ?','08RRR');
    
            echo "<pre>"; print_r($this->orders->getData()); die("dead");
            return $this->orders;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got My answer by by using the below code

```
public function getOrders()
    {
        //print_r($this->getRequest()->getParam('po_num'));
        $po_number = "%".$this->getRequest()->getParam('po_num')."%";
        if (!($customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId())) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!$this->orders) {
            $this->orders = $this->getOrderCollectionFactory()->create($customerId)->addFieldToSelect(
                '*'
            )->addFieldToFilter(
                'status',
                ['in' => $this->_orderConfig->getVisibleOnFrontStatuses()]
            );
            $this->orders->getSelect()
            ->joinLeft(
                ["sop" => "amt_sales_order_payment"],
                'main_table.entity_id = sop.parent_id',
                ['po_number']
            )
            ->where('sop.po_number LIKE ?',$po_number);
            
            $this->orders->setOrder(
            'ext_order_id',
            'desc'
            );
            //echo  $this->orders->getSelect()->__toString();
        }
        return $this->orders;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code in your function `getOrders()` to add payment filter

```
    $this->sales_order_table = "main_table";
    $this->sales_order_payment_table = $this->getTable("sales_order_payment");

    $this->orders->getSelect()
        ->join(array('sop' =>$this->sales_order_payment_table), $this->sales_order_table . '.entity_id= sop.parent_id');

    $this->orders->getSelect()->where("po_number=".$po_number);
```

Or try below way to join the table:

```
    /* join payment table */
    $this->orders->getSelect()
    ->join(
        ["sop" => $this->getTable("sales_order_payment")],
        'main_table.entity_id = sop.parent_id',
        array('po_number')
    )
    ->where('sop.po_number = ?','08RRR');
```

Hope this helps!